# Angular UI Bootstrap Tabs open on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, url-routing, angular-ui

I am using the tab directive from **Bootstrap UI** for my current **AngularJS** project and am heavily struggling with the implementation of **route-based tabs**.

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Dashboard"
             select="$parent.onTabSelected('dashboard')"
             active="$parent.isActive(this)">
        <!-- Content... -->
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

While the `select` attribute works okay for changing the route when clicking a tab heading I cannot get the `active` attribute to work as above (fails inside of angular-ui afterparsing the expression).

So my question is: why does the active attribute not work and is there a better way to bind the tabs to my route bidirectional?

**UPDATE:**
The following is my controller:

```
MainCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.rooms = [{
        id : 0,
        title : 'Room 1'
    }, {
        id : 1,
        title : 'Room 2'
    }];

    $scope.isActive = function(route) {
        if(('#/' + route) === location.hash) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    $scope.onTabSelected = function(tab) {
        var route;
        if ( typeof tab === 'string') {
            switch(tab) {
                case 'dashboard':
                    route = 'dashboard';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            route = 'rooms/' + tab.room.id;
        }
        window.location.hash = '#/' + route;
    }
};
```

The `isActive` method is called properly but then the following exception occurs:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at postLink (http://fakepath/bootstrap-ui/templates.js:2374:11)
```

Apparently, the `setActive` method inside of the directive function is not created for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you just trying to set a class to the tab to indicate that its active? Can we see you controller too?

Comment: Try this `ng-class="{active:isActive('dashboard')}`

Comment: This results in the following:Error: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 41 of the expression [{active: $parent.isActive('dashboard')} {active: active, disabled: disabled}] starting at [{active: active, disabled: disabled}].

Comment: Can I see you controller?

Comment: I added my controller code. If it is not sufficient I could also create a plunker

Comment: Plunkr please, that way I can debug it. Cheers

Comment: Just looking @ it, get rid of the `$parent` on the `active`. if it's in the same controller then there's no need for that.

Comment: That does not help either :S

Comment: Here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/wdE647iV6LfSrC7UaObY?p=preview

Comment: Can you view the plunkr? I can't see anything, I mean the Tabs.

Comment: You fixed it? It still does not work - same error message :/

Comment: I meant your plunkr code has some syntax error in it.

Comment: Okay, I found the reason for my error herehttps://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example as close as to your code without seeing it all, save this in as index.html and test, tried putting in plunkr(not testable in plunkr but works, but the source is there as well: http://embed.plnkr.co/TMN3KNlS4Dv90SvbTQKJ/index.html ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-controller="TabCtrl">
    <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" select="onTabSelected(tab.slug)">
        {{ tab.content }}
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).when('/room/:id', {
            controller: 'RoomCtrl',
        }).when('/dashboard', {
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'            
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }]);    

    var TabCtrl = function($scope) {
      $scope.tabs = [{
        slug: 'dashboard',
        title: "Dashboard",
        content: "Your Dashboard"
      }, {
        slug: 'room-1',
        title: "Room 1",
        content: "Dynamic content 1"
      }, {
        slug: 'room-2',
        title: "Room 2",
        content: "Dynamic content 2"
      }];
    };

    RoomCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

    };

    DashboardCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

    };    

    MainCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

      $scope.onTabSelected = function(tab) {
        var route;
        if (typeof tab === 'string') {
          switch (tab) {
            case 'dashboard':
              route = tab;
              break;
            default:
              route = 'rooms/' + tab;
              break;
          }
        }
        $location.path('/' + route);
      };

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: More specifically, clicking on tabs shows new URL but reloading the page returns back to the first tab instead of getting to the last clicked tab.

Comment: Where you trying this example with a newer version of angular? Angular  has changed significantly since 1.0.7

Comment: Yes, newer version. Have solved the problem meanwhile.